# gfortran compilation error: Size of 'put' argument of 'random_seed' intrinsic at (1) too small

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am trying to compile the following code with gfortran

```
program perm_field


implicit double precision(a-h,o-z)
parameter (pi=3.14159)

allocatable :: perm(:),alog_perm_all(:),u(:),xi(:),&
               perm_zone(:),alog_perm(:)
integer :: seed(2)
external    dgemm

open(unit=1,file='input.dat')
open(unit=3,file='random_log_perm.dat',access='append')
open(unit=31,file='random_log_perm_initial.dat',access='append')
open(unit=4,file='isim.dat')
open(unit=7,file='random_log_perm_updated.dat')
open(unit=5,file='kalman_index.dat')
open(unit=6,file='nsim.dat')
open(unit=8,file='perm_zone.dat')
open(unit=111,file='perm.dat')

read(4,*) isim
   seed(1)=isim;
   call random_seed(put=seed(1:2))
   call random_number(u)
```

But this is giving me error

```
   call random_seed(put=seed(1:2))
                        1
Error: Size of 'put' argument of 'random_seed' intrinsic at (1) too small (2/8)
```

It had worked with ifort, but I need to compile it using gfortran now.
What might be the problem and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Actually there's a lot of code between calling random seed and the top, I removed that while asking here!

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation on [`random_seed()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html#RANDOM_005fSEED). It states that `put` must be larger than or equal to the number returned by `size`.

So on my system a very quick test says `seed` should be at least 12.

```
program seed_test

        implicit none
        integer n

        n = 0

        call random_seed(size=n)
        write(*,*) 'n = ', n
end program seed_test
```

When I compile and run it:

```
$ gfortran -o seed_test seed_test.f90
$ ./seed_test
 n =           12
$
```

According to your error it must be at least **8**.

Comment: I made it 8 and it compiles now. thanks!